# secure keys or sensitive data in angular2 nativescript

Tags: mobile, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, man-in-the-middle, nativescript-plugin

I am curious to know of available options, that a developer can use to secure sensitive information inside the mobile application. This is to prevent anyone from breaking the app and use keys for some nefarious purposes. Example of sensitive data includes passwords of APIs, which app can use seamlessly in the background to retrieve data.

Code obfuscation can help but cannot prevent from stealing the information;

Local storage options such as nativescript-couchbase or nativescript-secure-storage -if my understanding is correct- depends on feeding the information manually after installing the app. But the information needs to be available inside the app at the time of shipping.

OAuth is not an option as it requires the user to login in order to receive the tokens. JWT is neither an option, as the APIs are protected just using basic authentication.

I am using nativescript/angular2 but i would appreciate any generic simple yet effective ideas..

Comment: See this blog post for some of the available options https://www.nativescript.org/blog/secure-your-mobile-app-protecting-the-code

Comment: I did read the article before asking here.. still I could not find how to secure my password., again I am not exploring any paid products.

Comment: in summary, i am looking to secure app secret credentials or API keys

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for obfuscation here, securing the information within your source code. By default {N} has uglify plugin configured within webpack, it gives the basic obfuscation.

There is [Jscrambler](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/secure-your-mobile-app-protecting-the-code) support which is paid.

Also, speaking of Sqlite, there is commercial version of the plugin that supports encryptions but I haven't tried it personally. You may feed your data into it and pack your db at build time then install the db on first launch.

Comment: Yeah I went through these options on the NativeScript site, but honestly,I am not looking at commercial options here. Thanks